how 123456 convert to '64' in char typecasting?
I get this output:
char c = 123456;

cout << c << endl;

warning: implicit conversion from 'int' to 'char' changes value from 123456 to 64 [-Wconstant-conversion]
    char c = 123456;
         ~   ^~~~~~
1 warning generated.

char is of 1 byte in C++ and has range -128..127 (signed) and 0..255 (unsigned), so 123456 can't be stored in it, that I understand. But, how does the compiler convert 123456 to char 64, which is ASCII '@'.
I was expecting it to give me an error or convert it, but I can not understand this conversion.

First, why did you tag dsa?  Did you read what the dsa tag is for?  Second, why so many computer languages?  Please tag one language.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post your code/errors as text, not images.  For people that can't see images for one reason or another your question is unanswerable.  We also can't copy the text from images, which stops us from being able to debug your code, i.e., help you.

What is 123456 % 256?

Why the [tag:java] tag? Do you really think that Java is the same as C++? And please consider the accepted answer to Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

You don't get an error, but you do get a warning telling you about the conversion. That should be enough. The message even tells you the value it will use.

You do get an error for this char c{123456}; however: https://ideone.com/1VD5fD

If you convert decimal 123456 to hexadecimal, you get 1E240.
A char, which is only 1 byte (8 bit for all currently interesting machines), can store 2 hex digits (1 hex digit is 4 bit, so 8 bits take 2 digits).
Thus, assigning the much-too-large 1E240 to a single char will leave hexdecimal 40 in that char-byte. Overflows in computer-software (generally) ditch the left digits and only keep whatever fits from the right.
Look up that hex 40 in ASCII tables (or convert to decimal 64 and look it up then) shows that this is the @ character.
Again, why ASCII? It's what all "relevant" encodings are built on, so I'm not even asking what your box is using because it's bound to be some derivative of ASCII...

That leads to the question, "What is the integral of ASCII?"
